# Stubbing method parameters in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Suppose I have a class

```
class A
  def initialize
  end

  def foo(a, b)
    # Do stuff
  end
end
```

When writing RSpec tests for this, how do I intercept the call to `foo` and modify it's parameters?

I might try something like the following that catches the method call, yields the params so I can modify them, and then calls the original method

```
my_obj = A.new

allow(my_obj).to receive(:foo) do |a, b|
  my_obj.foo("new", "values")
end

expect(my_obj.foo).to eq("bar")
```

However, the problem with this is that calling `A#foo` inside the block once again stubs that and yields a new block, producing an infinite recursive loop until the stack runs out of memory.

I know that `.and_call_original` method also exists, but can I yield the params with that and modify them before calling the original with the new modified params?

Or is there a way to "un-stub" the object inside the block so me calling it again doesn't cause a problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`and_wrap_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/wrapping-the-original-implementation):

```
my_obj = A.new

allow(my_obj).to receive(:foo).and_wrap_original do |original_method, a, b|
  original_method.call("new", "values")
end

expect(my_obj.foo).to eq("bar")
```